# Checked RadioButton

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a list of RadioButton :
RadioButton1
RadioButton2
RadioButton3
And I want to "Checked" one of this RadioButton using a variable :
string nameCheckBox = "RadioButton"+1;
And finally I want to do : nameCheckBox.IsChecked = true;

Is it possible ?

Comment: Why are you using a radiobutton in WP7?

Comment: It's for an application where you are able to change background color using radioButton.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ListPicker control? It's designed to replace RadioBoxes on WP7. -- It's easy to use, looks cool, and matches the WP7 paradigm (I've never seen a RadioButton on WP7, ever)

Comment: No, I didn't know the ListPicker control, but I will look at. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, but you have to make sure each RadioButton has a Name or an x:Name

```
int index = 1; // 1, 2 or 3 in your case
object element = FindName(string.Concat("RadioButton", index));
if (element != null && element.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
    ((RadioButton)element).IsChecked = true;
```

You can do the same thing for a CheckBox just replace RadioButton with CheckBox

Comment: And sorry for the mistake, it was just a "radioButton" in the example and no a "checkBox"

Comment: @Xavier - Is my solution correct? If so mark it as correct. If not how can I help you